# data.matrix() keeps producing lists

Tags: r, replace, lapply, datamatrix

I'm experiencing problem using the `data.matrix()` function along with `lapply`.
I have several .csv files which I've imported in a list, and each csv file is made of 84*84 matrix.
I want to replace all values in upper right half/ lower left half parts of the matrix to 0, so that it becomes approximately like this:

```
1100
1100
0011
0011
```

I figured that I should turn the dataframes to numeric matrices, and this is the code I used so far:

```
 files <- list.files(pattern="*.csv", full.names=F, recursive=F)
files

data1 <- lapply(files, function(x) {read.csv(x, header=F)})

data2 <- lapply(data1, function(x) replace(x,x=='NaN',0))

data3 <- lapply(data2, function(x) data.matrix(x, rownames.force = NA))

data4 <- lapply(data3, function(x) {x[c(43:84), c(1:42)] <- 0})
```

but the data.matrix() command doesn't seem to produce matrices, and instead it produces lists;
when I check the data with `class(data3[1])` , I keep getting list as the result.
Also when I ran the last line, all data in data4 turned to 0.

so I tried doing this:

```
val1 <- data3[1]
class(val1)
val1[c(43:84), c(1:42)] <- 0
```

and got the following error.

```
val1[c(43:84), c(1:42)] <- 0
Error in val1[c(43:84), c(1:42)] <- 0 : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

I have no idea why the `data.matrix()` code isn't working...
Would there be any way to fix the code, or another way to replace the values to 0?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: lapply returns a list of the same length as X, this is why it won't output matrices

Comment: I think data3[[1]] is the matrix you want.

Comment: @BrianMontgomery That is true, it did work out! but how can I do that with the lapply() code? I need to apply it to all my CSVs in the list...

Comment: It should all be there, just use the double brackets to access each data.matrix.